# The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS when installed Composer via Scoop

Tags: php, windows, openssl, scoop-installer

I've installed PHP and Composer via `scoop`, but it fails with error that SSL is missing:

```
>scoop install php composer
...
>composer selfupdate
composer: 1.6.5 (latest version)
  [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this
   error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSL extension isn't enable by default when PHP has been installed via Scoop.

To enable it, `extension=openssl` needs to be commented in the existing [`php.ini` file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production), or new `.ini` file can be created in PHP's `conf.d` directory.

The following command can locate `php.ini`:

```
php -i | grep -w ini
```

Then the following commands should solve the issue:

```
cd %HOMEPATH%\scoop\apps\php\current\cli\conf.d
echo extension=openssl >> openssl.ini
```

Respectively, similar files can be created for other extensions (such as `mbstring`, `mysqli`, etc.).

Related: [PHP/Composer issue (missing OpenSSL extension)](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/issues/1609).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I was getting errors in the log anyway. In the end I had to set full path in the ini file eg. `extension=C:\scoop\apps\php\current\ext\php_openssl.dll`.
Error was `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: ext\\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found), ext\\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found))`